# What Core Image Filters could be applied to improve an image of a text document?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-image, image-scanner

We have scanned several pages of a document using the iPhone camera. Now we want to apply some image filters to improve the quality of those scans, like to convert it to Black and White, remove shadows, high contrast, etc.

What CI Filters and parameters could we apply to improve the quality of the document image?

Answer (score 0):

There are many filter that you can Use. But I'll recommend some that can help you improving text quality.

1. CIMotionBlur
2. CIGaussianBlur
3. CIMedianFilter
4. Binarization